# Propagate Spring boot security context into a bean annotated with @KafkaListener

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-kafka

I have a bean that is annotated with `@KafkaListener` and inside this bean, I am planning to get the logged-in user credentials through `SecurityContextHolder`.

However, `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` is giving me a `null` object probably because this is running in a different `thread`.

In this case, is there a way to propagate the `SecurityContext` from `ThreadLocal` to another thread? Can it easily be done in my `Spring Boot` configuration?

Below is the sample code:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class MessageConsumer {

private final MessageService messageService;

@Autowired
public MessageConsumer(final MessageService service) {
    messageService = service;
}

@KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic")
public void receive(final List<Message> message) {
    messageService.consumerAnStoreMessage(message, SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The SecurityContext's authentication represents, for exemple, a user who called a webservice, a website's page... etc...

When you listen to a kafka message, which user's context should be used ?
I don't think what you are trying to do really makes sens.

Comment: That's correct. Since the `@KafkaListener` works really in the container thread, there is fully no way to correlate it with some user. Such a functionality is fully server-based and distinguished from any authenticated through Spring Security user. If you definitely need a user to call that service you need to authenticate exactly in that place of call. In this case your server becomes a user for that service. And it is going to work independently of any users on the MVC level. On the other hand you can propagate users through Kafka records and restore them during message process.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bi t late.
Maybe it can have sense, if you have an app that replicate change from other system (CDC) and you want to set than all change came from a specific user.

In that case, SpringSecurity allows you to configure the SecurityContextHolder mode (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContextHolder.html). You can set to Global with:
SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_GLOBAL)

Another option is to authenticate inside de method anotated with @KafkaListener